# Get scalar value from table in Kusto, KQL

Tags: database, azure-data-explorer, kql

I am trying to get the maximum of a column from a table and get the output of the data in the form of a scalar to be used in another table. I am attaching a sample code for reference here.

```html
Covid19
| limit 10
| summarize (max(Confirmed))
```

This gives me an output as in the following image:
[Result of Above Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Umhxb.png)

Now I want to get the value of the result as a scalar. I am new at KQL so maybe my approach as a whole can also be wrong any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `toscalar()` as part of a `let statement`.

For example:

```
let maxConfirmed = toscalar(
   Covid19
   | limit 10
   | summarize max(Confirmed)
);
... do something with 'maxConfirmed' ...
```